# why is there Black circles in my geometry in three.js?

Tags: three.js

js  and I am trying to create an earth with sphere geometry every things fine when I use this :

```
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 500, 64, 32 );
```

but when I try to make it bigger like this :

```
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 10000, 64, 32 );
```

it get a black circles in it like this : [image]

this is my earth geometry code :

```
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 10000, 64, 32 );
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'rgb(135,206,235)' , side: THREE.DoubleSide})  ;
  const sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  scene.add( sphere );
```

this is my camera code (I think the wrong is in it) :

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to set your `camera.far` property to a higher value. Right now it's set to `1,000` but with spheres that are `10,000` in radius, there are going to be parts of the circle that get clipped beyond the camera's maximum range. Those are the black areas you're seeing.

[See here for docs on the `Camera.far` property](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.far)